# php in_array between 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to determine which elements coincide in 2 arrays. The issue is that only the last element in my second array is selected instead of all 3. What am I missing here?

```
<?php
    
$containers = [
    0 => ['id'=>'1', 'name'=>'Peta'],
    1 => ['id'=>'2', 'name'=>'Epta'],
    3 => ['id'=>'3', 'name'=>'Fras'],
    4 => ['id'=>'4', 'name'=>'Maxs'],
    5 => ['id'=>'5', 'name'=>'Gtay'],
    6 => ['id'=>'6', 'name'=>'Prat'],
    7 => ['id'=>'7', 'name'=>'Drat'],
];

$invoices = [
    0 => ['id'=>'1', 'name'=>'Lebo'],
    1 => ['id'=>'3', 'name'=>'Efta'],
    2 => ['id'=>'4', 'name'=>'Gadr'],
];

foreach ($containers as $container) {
    
    foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
    
        if (in_array($container['id'], $invoice)) {
            $selected = 'selected';
        } else {
            $selected = '';
        }
    
    }
    
    echo $container['name'].' -> '.$selected.'<br>';
    
} ?>
```

Comment: There is a bunch of `array_*` functions in PHP, check them if you find something useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "break" after found in array.

```
<?php

$containers = [
    0 => ['id' => '1', 'name' => 'Peta'],
    1 => ['id' => '2', 'name' => 'Epta'],
    3 => ['id' => '3', 'name' => 'Fras'],
    4 => ['id' => '4', 'name' => 'Maxs'],
    5 => ['id' => '5', 'name' => 'Gtay'],
    6 => ['id' => '6', 'name' => 'Prat'],
    7 => ['id' => '7', 'name' => 'Drat'],
];

$invoices = [
    0 => ['id' => '1', 'name' => 'Lebo'],
    1 => ['id' => '3', 'name' => 'Efta'],
    2 => ['id' => '4', 'name' => 'Gadr'],
];

foreach ($containers as $container) {

    foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {

        if (in_array($container['id'], $invoice)) {
            $selected = 'selected';
            break;
        } else {
            $selected = '';
        }
    }

    echo $container['name'] . ' -> ' . $selected . '<br>';
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$containers = [
    [ 'id' => '1', 'name' => 'Peta' ],
    [ 'id' => '2', 'name' => 'Epta' ],
    [ 'id' => '3', 'name' => 'Fras' ],
    [ 'id' => '4', 'name' => 'Maxs' ],
    [ 'id' => '5', 'name' => 'Gtay' ],
    [ 'id' => '6', 'name' => 'Prat' ],
    [ 'id' => '7', 'name' => 'Drat' ],
];

$invoices = [
    [ 'id' => '1', 'name' => 'Lebo' ],
    [ 'id' => '3', 'name' => 'Efta' ],
    [ 'id' => '4', 'name' => 'Gadr' ],
];

$result = array_filter(
  $containers,
  fn($item) => in_array($item['id'], array_column($invoices, 'id'))
);

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Peta
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Fras
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Maxs
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the easiest solution was to create a new array:

```
foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
        $compare_id[] = $invoice['id'];
    } 
    
    foreach ($containers as $container) {
        
        if (in_array($container['id'], $compare_id)) {
            $selected = 'selected';
        } else {
            $selected = '';
        }
        
        echo $container['name'].' -> '.$selected.'<br>';
        
    }
```

Comment: psst! array_column()